# SQLite - Getting SUM from a Identical ID

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image]

I am wanting to get the subtotal for each Unique Order ID. For example, 3 orders made by OrderID 10248 would total to

> $168.0 + $98.0 + $174.0 = $440.0.

This is what I have so far in SQLite

```
SELECT OrderID, UnitPrice, Quantity, 
       Discount, '$' || ((UnitPrice * Quantity) - (Discount * (UnitPrice * Quantity))) 
    AS Subtotal
  FROM OrderDetail
```

I have tried GROUP BY OrderID, but that only gets the first Subtotal of each OrderID.

Any hints to getting the total would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting subtotals for each OrderID can be emulated by this query :

```
WITH OD AS
(
 SELECT OrderID, 
        UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount,
       (UnitPrice * Quantity) * ( 1 - Discount ) AS Subtotal
   FROM OrderDetail
)
SELECT * FROM OD 
UNION ALL
SELECT OrderID, Null, Null, Null, '$' || SUM( Subtotal ) 
  FROM OD
 GROUP BY OrderID  
 ORDER BY OrderID
```

Indeed, some other DB Management Systems use some functions and methods such as `Cube()`, `Rollup()` and `GROUPING SETS()`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=75f5e5fe8f91b1565f097b5d63a13f7b)</kbd>

Comment: How would you modify the code so that only the total for the OrderID is displayed?

Comment: I don't see what exactly you mean @user430574 . Do you ask about adding to or removing from GROUP BY list ?

Comment: As shown in the Demo which you have provided, taking OrderID 10248 for example, it lists the original 3, before the final total is printed. Is it possible to only show the final Subtotal/

Comment: of course, by removing `SELECT * FROM OD  UNION ALL` part from the query @user430574

Comment: If I was to join a different table so that the other table uses the subtotal calculated through this code, how would I modify the current code? Another table name = Order

Comment: Yes, @user430574 you can continue on using Common Table Expressions such as [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c5e8bdc2e4725c28a6a6d76acf09a6f5)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214841/discussion-between-user430574-and-barbaros-ozhan).